# Как называть параметры для функции

Tags: c, ооп, функции, любой-язык, параметры

Я сейчас пишу код в команде, скинул своему коллегу функцию:

```c
typedef struct      s_max
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int count;
}                   t_max;

t_max    max_count(t_max max, int x1, int y1, int count1)
{
    if (count1 > max.count)
    {
        max.count = count1;
        max.x = x1;
        max.y = y1;
    }
    return (max);
}
```

Он её исправил и сказал, что в ООП так делают:

```
t_max    max_count(t_max max, int x, int y, int count)
{
    if (count > max.count)
    {
        max.count = count;
        max.x = x;
        max.y = y;
    }
    return (max)
}
```

Имеет ли смысл писать код так? Мне показалось, что можно запутаться в том, где переменная, которую мы передали, и не эта переменная. Это нормальный тон?

Comment: Важно делать так чтоб было понятно читающему код. Если бы существовало "делать только так, и не иначе" - это было бы отражено в стандарте. Меня в этом коде куда больше беспокоит пропущенная звездочка...

Comment: @Harry поправил, теперь можно не переживать :D

Comment: Приведённая правка код более ООП-шным не делает :)
Это больше к читаемости.

Comment: Самая большая проблема у маньяков ООП в том, что всё *виртуально*. И будет ещё настаивать, чтобы все переменные имели одинаковые имена. Это приведёт к глобальному багу всей программы если все так будут делать.

Comment: Поправили. И стало совсем глупо - изменять поля в локальной переменной (аргументе). Вы же передаете `max` по значению, и теперь все, что вы с ним делаете в функции, благополучно теряется при выходе из нее... Я потому и писал о звездочке, а не о точке...

Comment: @Harry не понял, но у меня в цикл всё проходит, и меняются значения, при использовании этой функции

Comment: Что-то вы не то рассказываете... Смотрите сами: https://ideone.com/DncC3X

Comment: @Harry https://ideone.com/KGGUuu , да чуть-чуть не дописал, и правда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Считаю вполне нормально, сам так делаю и у других видел. Но в ООП обычно при обращении к "глобальным переменным" класса пишут this.x. На простом же С чтобы не спутать глобальную и локальную переменную, возможно лучше будет давать переменным разные имена.

В данном случае все переменные локальные и обозначив переменную как х1 можно предположить, что где-то должна быть и х2 (например координаты линии), на деле же у нас только одна точка в функции.

А вообще же в командной работе придется подстраиваться под команду, чтобы всем было привычнее и понятнее.

Comment: `Но в ООП обычно при обращении к глобальным переменным пишут this.x` - это не обращение к глобальным переменным, это обращение к полям объекта из метода объекта. Вне методов объектов это работать не будет.

Comment: Согласен, так более правильнее, я выразился по аналогии с не ООП программированием для переменных объявленных в этом же файле

Comment: В не-ООП вообще нет аналога this, и это уж точно не аналог глобальным переменным. Лучше вообще убрать это предложение.

Comment: В не-ООП раз уж на то пошло, нет private, public и protected полей.

Comment: Действительно, их там нет, но не знаю к чему это вообще

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы не было путаницы, идентификаторы должны быть максимально осмысленны.

В данном случае наличие индекса `x1, y1` на интуитивном уровне подсказывает, что где-то должны быть `x2, y2`. Поэтому правка вашего коллеги вполне оправдана.

Если есть твердое желание разделить имена параметров от остальных идентификаторов, то есть несколько способов.

Например, если функция `max_count` выполняется в цикле несколько раз, то можно было бы назвать параметры `xi, yi` или `new_x, new_y` или `current_x, current_y` и тому подобное.

Также в командах может быть выбран префикс для имен параметров. В Delphi правилом хорошего тона является использовать префикс `A`: `AX, AY, ACount`.

В разных проектах я встречал префиксы `P`, `P_` и просто `_`.